# regex match for vuejs syntax

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this regex expr `"( v-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)((=)(:)(\".+?\"))?""` which catches vue syntax

input : `<input v-on:click="inputevent" type="text" />`
returns `v-on`

Im trying to to implement one more conditions if the string contains
a html comment `<!--`

it should not return a match

teststring:  `<!-- <div id="my-div" v-bind:style="{ height: bigwidth }"> -->`
how can I implement this in the group ?

Comment: Could you add some examples of what sample input and output look like, compared to the expected result(s)? Makes the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think that context-free grammars, which is Vue syntax as well, cannot be expressed using regular expressions.